# What's the shortcut needed for this PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this PHP script:

```
    function myshortcode_title( ){
   return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'myshortcode_title' );
```

What is the shortcut i need for the page title to be shown? What do i need to put in the HTML for the fetched title to be shown

Comment: please be more specific .......??

Comment: This seems like a Wordpress question, Tag your Question with wordpress. You will get more relevant answers

Comment: @NareshKumar Updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your theme, or make an plugin from it.

```
/* title to get the post title  */
function getPageTitle() {
  global $wp_query;
  return get_post_title($wp_query->post->ID);
}

/* Add shortcode */
add_shortcode('page_title', 'getPageTitle');
```

for more [ShortCode Api](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: I've added the /* title to get the post title  */ code to my functions.php file, however when i add the shortcut [page_title] to the body of a page nothing happens

Comment: @YourDaily refer to link of shortcode api it will help you more to understand the API of wordpress

Comment: I've read it and it should work if i have the code [page_title] in the body, however it's still not working

Answer (score 1):

You may use this.

```
echo do_shortcode('[page_title]');
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/